# Why would a variable in PowerShell lose its value after it is referenced?

Tags: powershell

With the following 2 lines of code:

```
$meta = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetadata (Get-Command Get-Event)
$parametersInCmdlet = $meta.Parameters.GetEnumerator()
```

The $parametersInCmdlet variable is set as can be seen by referencing it.

```
$parametersInCmdlet

Key               Value
---               -----
SourceIdentifier  System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
EventIdentifier   System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
```

When I reference it again immediately after that, it appears empty (and confirmed if piped to Get-Member).

```
$parametersInCmdlet | gm
gm : No object has been specified to the get-member cmdlet.
At line:1 char:23
+ $parametersInCmdlet | gm
+                       ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand
```

There is nothing else [that should be] touching that variable in between those references.  This occurs in the console and ISE for both PS 2.0 and 3.0 so that makes me think it is more user misunderstanding than a bug.

What would cause the value to be lost in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned by `GetEnumerator()` methods is pretty much always an [`IEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx).  The job of an `IEnumerator` is to hand back elements of a collection, one at a time, until that collection is depleted.  At that point, it is the correct behavior for the `IEnumerator` to return back nothing when asked for the next item.

Powershell unrolls the entire collection when you look at it the first time.  Thus, by default, it is expected that you can't look at the collection again, since the `IEnumerator` has already been "spent."

The workaround is to call `Reset()` on the `IEnumerator` if you want it to start over.  Assuming the `IEnumerator` is properly implemented, this will allow you to re-read the collection from the beginning again.

So, try calling `$parametersInCmdlet.Reset()` before using it again.

Comment: The `IEnumerator` behavior explains why it returns the different values.  I have not been able successfully use `$parametersInCmdlet.Reset()` to get the original results back using it either before or after the second reference (even tough I see it as a method `$parametersInCmdlet.psbase | gm`).  This is not necessarily a big deal.  I need to find a way to test if the collection is empty without consuming or destroying it.  That may be another question after I do more research.

Comment: If you only need to check if the collection is empty, I would look at `$meta.Parameters.Count`  That way you never need to deal with weird enumeration issues.

Comment: Ahh.  I was using `$parametersInCmdlet.Count` and that was consuming the collection that I tried to use later.  I do one block of code when the collection is empty and another if there are values to iterate through.  It was the later code that was not acting as expected.  I will test my code using the two pieces of information above.